# Mongodb 3.2.11, I try to not upgrade automatically this version

Tags: mongodb, upgrade, updates

I have the MongoDB 3.2.11 installed on Debian 8 and with that configuration the MongoDB version is not pinned, is not working. What can I do to pin the MongoDB version (including the minor version)

Option 1:

#### Anchor MongoDB Packages

- Package: mongodb-org
- Pin: version 3.2.*
- Pin-Priority: -10

Option 2 from mongodb documentation:

Pin a specific version of MongoDB.
Although you can specify any available version of MongoDB, apt-get will upgrade the packages when a newer version becomes available. To prevent unintended upgrades, pin the package. To pin the version of MongoDB at the currently installed version, issue the following command sequence:

- echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
- echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
- echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
- echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
- echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

Please any TIPs or idea is welcome. Thanks a lot

Comment: did you update your `sources.list` with the version repository you want ?

Comment: Yes thanks, I use the version at sources but that's the MAJOR version, and I refer to pining the whole version including the MINOR version.

Comment: after runing `apt-get update` , then run `apt-cache madison mongodb-org`, make sure the version you need is stated there then run `apt-get install mongodb-org=version_number`

Comment: if you talking about doing a full system upgrade with `apt-get upgrade` i would advise you not to do it, only update the packages you need or you always use

Comment: if you talking about doing a full system upgrade with `apt-get upgrade` i would advise you not to do it, only update the packages you need or you always use

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I tested with the command that you recommend me and this is the output:

apt-cache madison mongodb-org

- `mongodb-org |     3.2.18 | https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/ jessie/mongodb-org/3.2/main amd64 Packages
- mongodb-org (others versions)
- mongodb-org |     3.2.11 | https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/ jessie/mongodb-org/3.2/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: This is the output of this command
apt-cache policy mongodb-org
- `mongodb-org:
  Installed: 3.2.11
  Candidate: 3.2.11
  Package pin: 3.2.11 (All look well)
  Version table:
  -   3.2.18 -10
        500 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/ jessie/mongodb-org/3.2/main amd64 Packages
   -   3.2.* (others versions)
 *** 3.2.11 -10
        500 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/ jessie/mongodb-org/3.2/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`
But any way automatic going to upgrade the minor version from .11 to .18

Comment: try `apt-get install mongodb-org=3.2.18`

Comment: Thanks a lot by your answer, but sorry that is not my objective, I explain again :). I have installed the 3.2 version with .11 minor version: 3.2.11, then when I did the upgrade, the mongodb upgraded automatic from 3.2.11 to 3.2 minor version .18, example 3.2.18, but I don't want that the mongodb upgrade it alone, I want pin the 3.2.11 and the mongodb not upgrade automatic to other minor version more high (that the mongodb keep it in the version 3.2.11)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/435416

Comment: Thanks a lot @0.sh, this command: apt-mark hold (package) help me to understand better this
Now I found one detail.
1_ If you excute apt upgrade, this not respect the pin priority and the hold dpkg status
2_ But if you executed apt-get upgrade, then yes respect the pin priority and the hold dpkg status

Then if some know how I can do the apt upgrade, respect the pin priority and the hold dpkg status, please you are welcome. :)

Comment: I found one solution, here there are some solutions: https://www.tecmint.com/disable-lock-blacklist-package-updates-ubuntu-debian-apt/ this option: using APT Autoremove File, worked perfect, just need add the mongodb packages to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove`, on section: `Never-MarkAuto-Sections`, and when you execute: apt upgrade, say that:
`The following packages have been kept back:
mongodb-org-mongos 
mongodb-org-server 
mongodb-org-shell 
mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.`
I hope this solution work to someone more... Thanks a lot